# API hitting for sam template resources gets internal server error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have been hitting out the API, the api's for console approach working fine.

However, the sam template resources api's are not working says `internal server error`.

Logs are not being generated on CloudWatch, made sure to include all the permissions.

Does anyone faced similar issue? Please help.

My sam template is:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: "SAM Template for Rekognition-related functions and API Gateway"

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10
    MemorySize: 256

Resources:
  StartModelFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      FunctionName: start-model-rekog
      Description: Lambda function to start a model in Rekognition
      CodeUri: start-model-rekog/
      Events:
        StartModelApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /start-model-rekog
            Method: get
            
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      StageName: v1
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: '2.0'
        info:
          title: 'startmodelrekog'
          version: '1.0'
        paths:
          /start-modelnew:
            get:
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: 'Successful response'
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${StartModelFunction.Arn}/invocations
                passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
                httpMethod: GET
                type: aws

  UploadDataFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      FunctionName: upload-data-rekog
      Description: Lambda function for uploading data
      CodeUri: upload-data-rekog/
      Events:
        UploadDataApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /upload-data-rekog/{bucket}
            Method: get

  UploadDataApi:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      StageName: v1
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: '2.0'
        info:
          title: 'uploaddatarekog'
          version: '1.0'
        paths:
          /{bucket}:
            get:
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: 'Successful response'
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${UploadDataFunction.Arn}/invocations
                passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
                httpMethod: GET
                type: aws_proxy

  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: testbucketsam-rekog

  ClassifyLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      FunctionName: classifyimage-rekog
      Description: Lambda function for classification
      CodeUri: classifyimage-rekog/
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref MyS3Bucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*

  StartModelFunctionApiGatewayPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt StartModelFunction.Arn
      Principal: 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGatewayApi}/*/*/*"

  UploadDataFunctionApiGatewayPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt UploadDataFunction.Arn
      Principal: 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGatewayApi}/*/*/*"

Outputs:
  StartModelFunctionArn:
    Value: !GetAtt StartModelFunction.Arn
  UploadDataFunctionArn:
    Value: !GetAtt UploadDataFunction.Arn
  ClassifyLambdaFunctionArn:
    Value: !GetAtt ClassifyLambdaFunction.Arn
```